# Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority

Tags: ssl, wget

When i am hitting x website with wget utility i am  getting the below error. But when i tried for other websites its working fine. And i see the Site x uses Proper SSL. Browser is not displaying any errors in it. What the way to troubleshoot this issue

wget https://x.com (Not working)
wget https://stackoverflow.com or google.com or facebook.com (Working)

Comment: Some websites have a proper TLS setup, others don't. Likely some chain issues, i.e. missing intermediate certificates. Check the site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).

Comment: Or a difference in the truststore, which in turn depends on which browser(s) and platform(s) you use(d) versus what build(s) of wget (which can use OpenSSL or GnuTLS, and both can use different truststore sources); ssllabs also checks _some_ 'standard' truststores. But in any case this is not a programming or development question or problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich. Yes when i tried with SSLLABS it says certificate chain was broken. SO what exactly needs to be done to solve the issue.

Comment: @user3309305: Ideally the server needs to be fixed. If this is not possible you need to import the missing chain certificates into your trust store. See for example [Downloading from a public server: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559526/downloading-from-a-public-server-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-i) for a detailed explanation and how to get the missing chain certificates and what to do with it.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich. I imported the intermediate certificates. My Problem Solves.